# Can't import via mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I am an absolute beginner in mongoDB. I am trying to import the sample data using mongorestore by doing the following:

```
C:\Users\hp\Downloads\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.3.1\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.3.1\bin>mongorestore --nsInclude=exampleDb C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData.gz
```

But I am getting the following error continuously:

```
2021-07-15T20:24:07.485+0530    Failed: file C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData.gz does not have .bson extension
2021-07-15T20:24:07.487+0530    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Then I also came to know that my file is unzipped, so for that I also tried doing:

```
mongorestore --gzip --nsInclude='exampleDb.*' C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData.gz
```

But the output remains the same.

I am using the mongoDB version 4.4.6
Can anyone tell me where and what am I doing wrong?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to restore a zipped file as for the path you have given to **mongorestore** tool:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData.gz
```

You can add the flag **--gzip** to sort the problem out.

```
mongorestore --gzip ...
```

As an alternative you can unzip the file on your machine and restore the output.

Comment: Hi @rafael I unzipped the file and changed my command to `mongorestore --nsInclude='exampleDb.*' C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData\sampleData` but the result is the same.

Comment: @Azan what's in the folder you unzipped? Maybe it isn't a valid MongoDB dump folder?

Comment: the full path of the extracted file is `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData\sampleData`

Comment: The structure is generally a folder called **dump** and the content are folders with the names of the  databases. The content of the database folder you should have **collection** files which have the extensions **.bson** and **.json**.

Comment: can you give me the steps that I should follow, because I am a beginner in this.
I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: I need to know what's in the **sampleData** folder and its subfolders. The error your are getting is due to **mongorestore** not finding the data files with extension  **.bson**.

Comment: Yes for sure the `sampleData` folder has the extracted `sampleData` file.

Comment: What's the extension of the file? Try to move the `sampleData` folder to a folder called `dump` and then rerun `mongorestore` with the path to the `dump` folder. You also don't need the flag `--nsInclude`. You can remove that.

Comment: the extension of the unzipped file is .gz
I copied the folder and pasted in the dump folder on the mongodb-tools folder, and ran `mongorestore C:\Users\hp\Downloads\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.3.1\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.3.1\bin\dump\data\sampleData` but got the error `don't know what to do with file "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.3.1\mongodb-database-tools-windows-x86_64-100.3.1\bin\dump\data\sampleData\sampleData", skipping...`

Comment: From inside the folder where the `dump` folder is located, try running:
`mongorestore dump`

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of MongoDB, we can use mongorestore like this:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive="fullpath to your file" --db "db name"
```

In **newer versions**, as **--db is deprecated**, we can use mongorestore in this way:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive="fullpath to your file" "db name"
```

In your case you should probably enter this command:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\aqa-test-tools\TestResultSummaryService\data\sampleData.gz  exampleDb
```